# How to implement this interesting List/Grid view animation using Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am looking for a way to replicate the animation as shown below. When a user taps on the cell, I want the image to animate and traverse to the target. How would I go about animating from a grid/list to a widget outside of gridview? How do I dynamically calculate the start and end positions for the grid item to traverse?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Draggable` and `DragTarget`. Draggable and DragTarget allows us drag a widget across screen.

Check out these links

[Flutter Drag & Drop for Two-Year-Olds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOh6CkX-d6U)

[A Deep Dive Into Draggable and DragTarget in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-draggable-and-dragtarget-in-flutter-487919f6f1e4)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't plan to drag and drop. I just need a visual representation of an item being animated when tapping on a grid cell.